# SKAction from stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm trying to make a space-invaders-ish game that goes through levels automatically. The way I've been trying to do so is by running an action, that dynamically run another x SKAction.
Example:

```
int currentLevel = 1;

[self runAction: lvl(currentLevel) ]; //Run lvl1 when currentLevel = 1, lvl2 when = 2, etc.

SKAction *lvl1 = ...  
SKAction *lvl2 = ...
```

etc.

How can I get the `runAction:` to read an `NSString` object?

This is the code that I've tried:

```
int currentLevel = 1;

[self runAction:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lvl",currentLevel]];

SKAction *lvl1 = [SKAction sequence:@[sBA,sBA]]];
```

But that obviously didn't work because the program expected an `SKAction` instead of a `NSString`.

Comment: This is an XY problem.  You don't need `runAction:` to read `NSString` objects (it can't).  What you need is a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some sort of collection.

For example, with an array.  Create an array and fill it with level objects:

```
NSMutableArray *levels = [NSMutableArray array];

[levels addObject:[SKAction sequence:@[sBA,sBA]]; //etc. do this for each level
```

And when you're ready to run one of them:

```
int currentLevel = 0;

[self runAction:[levels objectAtIndex:currentLevel]];
```

Comment: Just depends on actual usage.  If his levels are simply number and he intends to progress through them in order, an array is better.  If the levels are named and there's no order, but he wants to access specific ones at the user's choice, a dictionary may be better.  You could also use an `NSMutableSet` even.  The main point here is to use SOME sort of collection.